# Rails React Component Renders But Not Visible on Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I just added the react-rails gem to my project and tried to add a react component to my index.html.erb file. I used the react component generator to make a simple message/text element, but it does not show up on my view after I deploy to Heroku, but it seems to render when I inspect the page. I have no idea why this isn't working.

Please look at the images I have attached. It looks like the javascript doesn't get compiled??

[Body inspection part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcyyv.png)

index.html.erb code

```
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <%= react_component('Message', text: 'hello') %>
    <h3>Products TEST REACT </h3>
```

Message.jsx code

```
var React = require("react")
class Message extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Text: {this.props.text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Message.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string
};
module.exports = Message
```

[HTML body inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv4QC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to the git commit before installing react-rails and used the shakacode react-on-rails gem instead and got it to work